# Asus EEE PC 1005HA (XP Home) refuses to connect to Virgin Mobile MiFi

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, netbook, dhcp

My client has an Asus EEE PC model 1005HA, and we're attempting to connect it to the WiFi network created by a VirginMobile MiFi unit.

They also have a MacBook Pro with Snow Leopard that has absolutely no issue connecting to the MiFi.

The specific symptom is that the netbook fails to lease an IP address from the MiFi unit. I supply the 12-digit numerical password (WPA) to the netbook, it throws a 'waiting for network' dialog with an indeterminate progress indicator, and then times out.

**Update:** We've determined that this behavior has stopped when the EEE PC and the MiFi unit were taken out of the client's home, and to a different home that didn't have an existing wifi network. Similarly, when taken to a third location that didn't have wifi, the EEE PC and MiFi got along swimmingly.

My current theory is that the existing wifi networks and the wifi leg of the MiFi unit are on the same channel and competing with one another. Perhaps the MacBook Pro has the capability to overcome this interference, while the EEE PC doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the drivers, I had the same problem.  Here is a link where I got the latest files. http://www.atheros.cz/

You will need to go to device manager and select your wireless device to find out what model it is and then download the proper file and run the installer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that this is *not* an official driver site. I'd recommend getting them from Asus.